# The necessary and sufficient condition of a linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have known that if $E$ is a $K$-vector space, and $F$ is a subset of $E$, then $F$ is a linear subspace if and only if:

- $F \ne \emptyset$
- $\forall (x, y) \in F^2,\ then \ x + y \in F  $
- $\forall\lambda\in K,\ \forall x \in F, then \ \lambda x\in F$

From this, I can also prove that $F$ is a linear subspace if and only if:

- $F \ne \emptyset$
- $\forall(\lambda,\mu)\in K^2,\ \forall (x, y) \in F^2, then \ \lambda x + \mu y\in F$

But I have read from some textbooks that there is another condition for $F$ to be a linear subspace. The condition is that $F$ is a linear subspace if and only if:

- $F \ne \emptyset$
- $\forall\lambda \in K,\ \forall (x, y) \in F^2, then \ \lambda x + y\in F$

I have managed to prove the necessary condition ($F\ is\ linear \ subspace \implies ...)$. But for the sufficient condition ($F\ is\ linear\ subspace \impliedby ...)$, I still do not know how to prove it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda,\mu\in K$ and $x,y\in F$. We have

$$(\underbrace{\lambda-1}_{=\lambda'})x+y\in F$$
and

$$(\underbrace{\mu-1}_{=\mu'})y+x\in F$$
so if we add it we get

$$\lambda x+\mu y\in F$$

**Remark** Notice that if $x,y\in F$ and with $\lambda=1$ we get $x+y\in F$. This justifies that the sum of two vectors of $F$ is a vector of $F$.